# render partial on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, renderpartial

I would like to call partials on some standard operations. I am using this method for calling the partial:

```
 %li= link_to 'Delete Event', 'javascript:void(0);', :class => 'alert tiny button', :data => {'reveal-id' => :RevealDelete}
= render 'layouts/reveal_delete', :item => event_display(@event.event), :resource => @event
```

Then in my partial,

```
#RevealDelete.reveal-modal


 %a.close-reveal-modal ×
  %h3= "Delete #{item}"
  %p Are you sure you want to delete this?
  =link_to "Delete #{item}", resource, :method => :delete, :remote => :true, :confirm => resource, :class => 'button close-reveal-modal'
  %a.button.alert.close-reveal-modal Cancel
```

How can I have this has as something like:

```
link_to 'Delete', '#', :partial => 'layouts/delete', :remote => :true?
```

so that I only render that partial when clicked and not when the page loads?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do that with javascript like:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", delete_content_path, :remote => true %>
```

The action in your corresponding controller then will be this:

**My Controller:**

```
def delete_content
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end        
end
```

Then you can create the `delete_content.js.erb` inside your correct directory of the link and there you put the following code:

**delete_content.js.erb**

```
$('#div_id').html("<%= render :partial => 'my_partial' %>");
```

Then in your view:

**delete_content.html.erb**

```
<div id = "div_id">
#this div is html div that will render your partial

</div>
```

Don't forget to put your partial **_my_partial.html.erb** in the same folder.

Comment: just for notice, `format.js` will use partial like `action_method_name.js.erb`. SO in case you'll need to render 2 partials, you need to specify name of another partials

Comment: im getting this error `undefined local variable or method `delete_content_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd6972c1a58>:0x007fd6972c9320>` do i need create a route for this to work?

Comment: added the route, to my routes.rb though it doesnt appear to be rendering anything :S

Comment: seems that the js file doesnt seem to be actioning anything

Comment: Please note that you should have some contents in file `_my_partial.html.erb` so that the div should display within it.

Comment: I have content in my partial, its the rendering from the jquery that doesnt appear to be working

Comment: i think its something relating to this line `$('#RevealDelete').html("<%= render :partial => 'reveal_delete' %>");`

Comment: So do you have `_reveal_delete.html.erb` with the contents in it? And also do you have div with `<div id = "RevealDelete"></div>` in your file where you defined your `link_to`? In my above code `link_to` must belong to `delete_content.html.erb` because there only you are rendering. Make sure that all.

Comment: i have all of those things, still no go

Comment: What about if the person clicks New Tab or New Window on the partial.  If you have the respond to in place the new tab will have a blank page which is ok.  But wouldn't it be better to prevent this from happening to not make this a link_to and make the onclick trigger the partial rendering?

Comment: I have the same question as the OP, tried this solution and got the same error. This solution does not work or fails to address whatever is causing the `undefined local variable or method` error. @BossNass, did you ever find a proper solution or what was causing the error?

Answer (score 17):

To add to the accepted answer, I only got it to work after changing the js portion to the following:

```
$('#div_id').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'my_partial') %>");
```

Without the `escape_javascript` it was just rendering the partial in the background and not updating the view.

Answer (score 0):

on the view do this:

```
link_to "Delete #{item}", '/model/confirm_deletion', :method => :delete, :remote => true #add the class and extra attributes if neeeded
```

on your controller

```
def confirm_deletion
end
```

and add a view to the confirm_deletion action in js

```
#RevealDelete.reveal-modal
  %a.close-reveal-modal ×
  %h3= "Delete #{item}"
  %p Are you sure you want to delete this?
  =link_to "Delete #{item}", resource, :method => :delete, :remote => :true, :confirm => resource, :class => 'button close-reveal-modal'
  %a.button.alert.close-reveal-modal Cancel

:javascript
  $(body).append($('#RevealDelete'));
```

that would make an ajax request to load that custom confirmation dialog, maybe you want to add some wrapper to insert the dialog instead of using body.append