# Trigger a click with jQuery using link_to of rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I'm working on a Rails 4 app. I need to trigger a click in a link using javascript (or jQuery). I have this in my view:

```
<%= link_to t('.fixture'), fixture_manager_tournament_path(format: :js), remote: true, id: 'fixture-link' %>
```

this generates:

```
<a id="fixture-link" data-remote="true" href="/manager/tournaments/1/fixture.js">Fixture</a>
```

Notice the `remote: true`.
This is working fine when I click the link, but I need to simulate the click through js. 
I've tried with:

```
$('#fixture-link').click();
$('#fixture-link').trigger('click');
$('#fixture-link').trigger('click.rails');
```

But none of them are working. 
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

@RustComet Comet It should replace the HTML of one of my divs...

@RichPeck I have a view too big. Then, to avoid long rendering time, I'm trying to load partials through JS. I've used this info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174908/3893506 to achieve that.

My view have various tabs and all of they are loaded through JS (except one). Then I added an additional parameter to the route in order to access directly to the desired tab. So I can go to `/tournament?active=fixture` and see the fixture.

The issue is, the tab is active but the content isn't here. (Of course, the ajax request and callbacks aren't fired until I clic on the link). That is why I'm trying to simulate a clic on that link and load the corresponding tab.

Comment: Is `$('#fixture-link').click();` producing any kind of error? Could you open the debugger and try to access `$('#fixture-link')` to see whether it is `undefined`?

Comment: The middle line should do the trick. Have you wrapped your JavaScript code in a `$(document).ready()` block?

Comment: @brito No, there is no error in the console. If I access to `$('#fixture-link')` in the console it returns the correct object. `<a id="fixture-link"...` 


@RyanK Yes I wrapped the JS in `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... })`
Also, executing `$('#fixture-link').trigger('click');` in the Chrome console doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is it possible that the JS event is in fact firing but not returning anything?

Comment: Why do you need to simulate the click?

Comment: Thanks for your support! I've updated the original question with more info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved! I've solved this by loading the correct JS and executing it directly, using the 'active' parameter and without need a click on the links.
Thanks to everyone who helped me!

If someone wants to know, this is the code I've used (its coffeescript):

```
tournament = $('#main-wrapper').data('tournament')
$.get '/manager/tournaments/' + tournament + '/fixture.js', (data) -> data
```

Answer (score 9):

Though its very late and you have got your problem solved, but here is the actual solution  :)

```
$('#fixture-link')[0].click();
```

You missed `[0]` portion.