# Is it possible to render partial with ajax request in Rails 5 view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a view with some information and a `render partial: 'path/to/partial'`

I want to do something like `render url: another_model_path(@model), remote: true`.

I could partially accomplish what I wanted with `link_to 'Load what I want', another_model_path(@model), remote: true`

However, I'd need to click the button to load the content I want. Is there anyway to do this without clicking any button and preferably not using custom javascript (just something like remote: true)

I saw that it is possible to add data-remote=true to any element, and Rails will take care of making the ajax request (as long as you also provide data-url='your_url'). I tried this in a  but it didn't work. I tried it in a check_box_tag and it works, but again, I would need to click the checkbox )=

Thanks in advance.

Comment: saying without click, just do `<%= render 'PATH' %>` and it will load for u that page. No, if u want to render the partial dynamically, event or action has to be triggered...

Comment: <%= render 'PATH' %> wouldn't do in my case. I need the controller to be fired, not just rendering html. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a non-ideal solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321189/2565946). Basically just use js to fire a request to the controller I want like:

in the view:

```
.some-class{ data: { remote="true", url: my_path(@model), method: :get } }
  .loading= fa_icon "spinner pulse", class: "fa-5x"
```

and in the .js:

```
$ ->
  elem = $("div").find("[data-remote]")
  path = elem.data("url")
  method = elem.data("method") || "GET"
  defaultContent = elem.contents()

  elem.bind 'ajax:beforeSend', ->
    $(this).prepend(defaultContent)
    $(this).contents().css("opacity", "0.5")

  $.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: 'script',
    type: method,
    complete: ->
      defaultContent.remove()
  })
```